# How to get setAttribute() to work in javascript when we just created the element in the function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I tried console.log() to see if zoomName has a value, and it does. However, I was trying to see if setAttribute() worked in the function by console logging the id of the div I just created and it said it's unidentified. How do I set attribute in this case? Thanks!

```
var zoomNum = 0;
function appendImg(imgName){
    zoomNum+=1;
    var zoomName = zoomNum.toString();          //create id name for new zoom class
    zoomName = "zoomId" + zoomName;

    var newZoomClass = document.createElement("div");         //create new zoom class for each image
    newZoomClass.setAttribute("class", "zoom");
    newZoomClass.setAttribute("id", zoomName);            //new ID

    document.getElementsByClassName("infoContent")[0].appendChild(newZoomClass);  //append class to infoContent

    var linkk = document.getElementsByClassName("zoom");
    var theValue = linkk.getAttribute("id");
    console.log(theValue);
```

Comment: `val`? Did you mean `var`?

Comment: You never added the element to the DOM, how do you expect `getElementsByClassName()` to find it?

Comment: Also, `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not a single element.

Comment: typo at declaring linkk?

Comment: @Phil That must be a copying error or the code wouldn't even run.

Comment: @Barmar too many times I ask if there's any errors in the console and they say no. Then later they say something like _"oh, except for these errors but I thought they meant nothing"_

Comment: @Phil He says he's getting undefined. If the script can't even be parsed he wouldn't get that.

Comment: @Barmar they say they're getting _"unidentified"_ so who knows what to believe. Anyway, I'm sure you're right and it's just a typo here in the question

Comment: @phil oh sorry bout that, I changed val to var, and moved the console.log after I appended the div to a class, check my edited question

Comment: @KarenC in that case, simply see the linked duplicate post. `getElementsByClassName()` does not return what you expect

Comment: @Phil  actually just wanted to check if the attributes were created. In this case, they should have been created right?

Comment: Yep, there shouldn't be any problems with the attributes that you set

Comment: Oh okay thank you!